# How to give sudo permission for a user to execute limited set of commands as other user in linux

Tags: linux, shell, tomcat, redhat, sudo

we are preparing a script to automate the tomcat patching in our environment, there are two users, one is patching user "puser" and tomcat user which is different from server to server but it follows a common naming convention example tc_. example "tc_xxxxx"

as a part of automation, it is mandatory that patch user "puser" should execute the patching for tomcat, some execution of commands needs to executed as tomcat user "tc_xxxxx" so we gave sudo permission for "puser" to execute some commands as "tc_xxxxx"

we used the following sudo permissions, but it is not working and asks for password.

```
Cmnd_Alias      TOMCAT_APPLCHMOD = /usr/bin/su  tc_[a-zA-Z0-9_.]* -c "/usr/bin/chmod -R 755 /appl/*",/bin/su  tc_[a-zA-Z0-9_.]* -c "/bin/chmod -R 755 /appl/*"
Cmnd_Alias      TOMCAT_KILLTOMCAT= /usr/bin/su - tc_[a-zA-Z0-9_.]* -c "kill -9 [0-9]*",/bin/su - tc_[a-zA-Z0-9_.]* -c "kill -9 [0-9]*"
Cmnd_Alias      TOMCAT_RM_LOGWEBAPP = /usr/bin/su - tc_[a-zA-Z0-9_.]* -c /usr/bin/rm -rf /web/tomcat.*/logs/* /web/tomcat.*/logs /web/tomcat.*/webapps/* "/web/tomcat.*/webapps",/bin/su - tc_[a-zA-Z0-9_.]* -c /bin/rm -rf /web/tomcat.*/logs/* /web/tomcat.*/logs /web/tomcat.*/webapps/* /web/tomcat.*/webapps
MW_TOMCAT_USERS ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:TOMCAT_WEBCHMOD,TOMCAT_JBCSCHMOD,TOMCAT_APPLCHMOD,TOMCAT_SERVICE_STARTSTOP,TOMCAT_SYSTEMCTL_STARTSTOP,TOMCAT_KILLTOMCAT,TOMCAT_RM_LOGWEBAPP,TOMCAT_CHOWN_TOMCAT,TOMCAT_CHGRP_TOMCAT,TOMCAT_APPSTART,TOMCAT_RM_TOMBK
```

but it works when i add the following  sudo persmission

```
Cmnd_Alias      TOMCAT_APPLCHMOD = /usr/bin/su  tc_[a-zA-Z0-9_.]* -c "/usr/bin/chmod -R 755 /appl/*",/bin/su  tc_[a-zA-Z0-9_.]* -c "/bin/chmod -R 755 /appl/*"
Cmnd_Alias      TOMCAT_KILLTOMCAT= /usr/bin/su - tc_[a-zA-Z0-9_.]* -c "kill -9 [0-9]*",/bin/su - tc_[a-zA-Z0-9_.]* -c "kill -9 [0-9]*"
Cmnd_Alias      TOMCAT_RM_LOGWEBAPP = /usr/bin/su - tc_[a-zA-Z0-9_.]* -c /usr/bin/rm -rf /web/tomcat.*/logs/* /web/tomcat.*/logs /web/tomcat.*/webapps/* "/web/tomcat.*/webapps",/bin/su - tc_[a-zA-Z0-9_.]* -c /bin/rm -rf /web/tomcat.*/logs/* /web/tomcat.*/logs /web/tomcat.*/webapps/* /web/tomcat.*/webapps

Cmnd_Alias      TOMCAT_SUDO =  /usr/bin/su - tc_[a-zA-Z0-9_.]*

MW_TOMCAT_USERS ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:TOMCAT_WEBCHMOD,TOMCAT_JBCSCHMOD,TOMCAT_APPLCHMOD,TOMCAT_SERVICE_STARTSTOP,TOMCAT_SYSTEMCTL_STARTSTOP,TOMCAT_KILLTOMCAT,TOMCAT_RM_LOGWEBAPP,TOMCAT_CHOWN_TOMCAT,TOMCAT_CHGRP_TOMCAT,TOMCAT_APPSTART,TOMCAT_RM_TOMBK,TOMCAT_SUDO
```

but this gives all rights to "puser" as the tomcat user "tc_xxxxx" .  this is not acceptable as the patching user should not have all the rights of tomcat user.

please suggested a way to limit the tc_xxxxx commands to patching user "puser"

Comment: Could you give an example of a typed command that you expected to work without a password, but it didn't?

Comment: please find the example below,

[puser@server1 web]$ ps -ef |grep tomcat
tc_beast  13277      1  0 Oct18 ?        00:04:32 /usr/java/default/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.fi tomcat catalina.startup.Bootstrap start

[puser@server1 web]$ sudo su - tc_beast -c "kill -9 13277"

We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.

[sudo] password for puser:

Comment: One thing to be noted is that *sudoers* wildcards are not regular expressions, so `[0-9]*` means a digit followed by any sequence of zero or more characters, which is probably not what you intended. Also, wildcards inside quoted strings do not seem to work very well.